# libclang get AST tree of macro extension

Tags: c, macros, libclang

I'm currently busy with using libclang library.

My goal is to parse code that contains macro with parameters and to get the type of the macro parameters in order to make syntax coloration.

If we consider the following piece of code

```
#define MACRO(X) X

typedef struct
{
  int a;
} aType;

aType data;

int var = MACRO(data.a);
```

My goal is to be able to color the field `a` of the structure `aType` on the line `int var = MACRO(data.a)`. I.e. I would like to get the line, column and type whenever I'm getting a cursor over the field `a` of `data` variable.

The problem is that whenever I'm getting the cursor on the position of character `a`, its type is `CXCursor_MacroExpansion`. I've already tried to get the referenced cursor (via `clang_getCursorReferenced`) but then I'm getting a cursor type `CXCursor_MacroDefinition`.

I've also already tried to visit the child via `clang_visitChildren` but this returning the cursor itself as well, so it is not useful.

If I could get a cursor with type `CXCursor_MemberRefExpr` out of my cursor with type `CXCusor_MacroExtension` I would have what I need.

Does anyone have an idea how to actually get the info of expanded code iso getting `CXCursor_MacroExpansion`, whenever cursor is over a macro expansion?

Thanks a lot for your time and help.

Kind regards,

Laurent

Comment: I guess that some LLVM mailing list would be a better place to ask

Comment: I'm giving a try, thanks a lot for the idea. So far I didn't received any update yet from the mailing list. If I find the solution, I'll come here to update my question with the answer. That might help other people.

Comment: https://xkcd.com/979/

Comment: Hi Kornel, I'm afraid I didn't see anything yet :( I'm still living with this issue... Thanks anyway for the nice link shared ;)